# How to connect words/phrases in matlab

Tags: matlab

How can I connect these two parts?

In Excel if you say 'state'&2 you will get a combined phrase state2.

I want to join 'state' and 'i' where i is a number between e.g. 1,2,3...

Then I can end up with state1 or state5 for example depending on what i is equal to.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can

1. Use `num2str` to convert `2` to `'2'`, and then concatenation to build your char array
2. Use `sprintf` to create a char array with a specified placeholder format
3. Use strings.

Importantly here I've made a distinction between strings (`"double quotes"`) and character arrays (`'single quotes'`) - read [here](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/characters-and-strings.html) for more details about their differences.

Corresponding code would look like

```
% 1. Use num2str and concatenation
str = ['state', num2str(2)]; % -> 'state2' (char)

% 2. Use sprintf
str = sprintf( 'state%d', 2 ); % -> 'state2' (char)

% 3. Use strings
str = "state" + 2 % -> "state2" (string)
```

I would opt for number 2, since I think it's cleaner than 1 and more flexible, and I have used MATLAB since before strings existed so I'm predisposed to dislike them!